# Gradle Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, gradle, slf4j, intellij-idea-2016

I have tried to get this working for three days now in my project and created a simple project to test. I searched around very similar issues on here but didn't find anything that helped with how to solve the error I'm getting. I went even as far as reformatting my Fedora 25 as it works on a Windows 10 but still nothing. I have also enabled in both settings and other settings in Intellij-2016.3.4 annotation processing which according to other answers should have fixed it but, it doesn't change anything. Please any help will be appreciated!!!

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at
>   com.sammy.CheckLog.(CheckLog.java:8) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           **at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)**
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 1 more

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

    @Slf4j
    public class CheckLog {

        public static void main(String... args){
            log.info("I'm Here!! ");
        }
    }
```

Below is my build.gradle file having lombok defined along with the associated slf4j dependencies.

```
 /*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a commented-out sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.sammy.CheckLog'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compileOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'
    compileOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.24'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**UPDATE**: After changing to "compile", this runs on the commandline not from Intellij as it seems to use it's own runtime to interpret it while gradle uses the one I've defined. jdk1.8.0_121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not added the SL4J JAR files at runtime, because you used it for compile-only.
Change your build.gradle file for the SLF4J dependencies to `compile` instead of `compileOnly`:

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.24'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm able to run it on the commandline for it to work now. But, when I run it with Intellij it still throws the same error message and because I've got some database app in Intellij to run end-to-end testing, I need it to work there as well.

Comment: Try to re-import the project in IntelliJ.

Comment: it still fails :-(

Comment: 'at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)' That line is missing from the stacktrace which tells me Intellij is trying to use it's own runtime library to execute the code not the jre defined which is what gradle uses to run the program. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Did a test on my machine: simulated the same issue and then I went to the "Gradle Projects" tab and clicked the "Refresh all Gradle projects" button, and it did the trick by correcting the libraries imported. (I imported my file as a Gradle project, bu opening the build.gradle from my project's folder with no IntelliJ configs)

Comment: Hey Boschi, how do I open build.gradle with no Intellij config?

Comment: In project folder, rename/delete the folder  '.idea'

Comment: _Error:Failed to load project configuration: cannot read file ./././.idea/misc.xml: ./././.idea/misc.xml (No such file or directory)_ . That's what I get when I deleted the .idea folder and tried to run it.

Comment: In IntelliJ, Close the project, in the project folder delete the .idea dir. Back in IntelliJ, go to File -> Open  and select the `build.gradle` from your project's folder. This will make IntelliJ open it as if it were a "new" project and reconfigure it with the info in your gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

I have some problem. IntelliJ Idea 2016.3 and Gradle 3.4.1

Initialized a new project with:

`gradle init --type java-application`

added couple lines to build.gradle

`compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.24'`

added line to App.java:

`...
static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
...`

And now you have error in Idea, but in terminal project will run ok (with gradle run)

[Error in IntelliJ Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3AYF.jpg)

Update: I found that if I'm initializing a project with a gradle 3.3 (not 3.4.1) then error leave. Maybe this behavior related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167412

Answer (score 1):

Change: `compileOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'` to `compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'`

Comment: Thanks! I'm able to run it on the commandline for it to work now. But, when I run it with Intellij it still throws the same error message and because I've got some database app in Intellij to run end-to-end testing, I need it to work there as well.

Comment: @Sammy65 it should also work in Intellij. can you refresh your Project?

Comment: I have refreshed the project several times but still no joy